# MongoDB Sharding Error in Production

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sharding

We implemented mongodb sharding concept for our chat module by using node + mongodb.

```
MongoDB Sharding Configuration
===============================
Shard1 = PRIMARY + SECONDARY + ARBITER
Shard2  = PRIMARY + SECONDARY + ARBITER
Config
Mongos
```

Following details we got it on today morning. But we dont know how we can resolve this issue.

Please let me know how we can resolve this issue.

**"errmsg" : "rollback 2 error findcommonpoint waiting a while before trying again"**

**"errmsg" : "error RS102 too stale to catch up"**

```
data2:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "data2",
    "date" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:30:29Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "50.52.108.16:20001",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 9,
            "stateStr" : "ROLLBACK",
            "uptime" : 322,
            "optime" : {
                "t" : 1343361602000,
                "i" : 155
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:00:02Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:30:29Z"),
            **"errmsg" : "rollback 2 error findcommonpoint waiting a while before trying again"**
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "50.52.108.17:20002",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "optime" : {
                "t" : 1343363429000,
                "i" : 7
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:30:29Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "50.52.108.17:20003",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 10880311,
            "optime" : {
                "t" : 0,
                "i" : 0
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:30:28Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}

data1:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "data1",
    "date" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:30:17Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "50.52.108.17:10001",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 3,
            "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
            "uptime" : 35,
            "optime" : {
                "t" : 1343320338000,
                "i" : 3
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-07-26T16:32:18Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:30:16Z"),
            "errmsg" : "error RS102 too stale to catch up"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "50.52.108.16:10002",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "optime" : {
                "t" : 1343363417000,
                "i" : 30
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:30:17Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "50.52.108.16:10003",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 10880162,
            "optime" : {
                "t" : 0,
                "i" : 0
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2012-07-27T04:30:16Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Kumaran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the secondary was down for a very long period of time and now it can't come in sync with the primary. This sync requires the oplog to contain all the writes going to the primary during the secondary's down-time. If the secondary has been down for too long, the records might have been rolled out of the oplog since it is a "capped" collection.You need to do a full resyc:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Resyncing+a+Very+Stale+Replica+Set+Member
Thereafter, consider increasing the oplog size to avoid a similar situation in future.

Comment: Also check out these links: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3126 , https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/0qaUCg6GSFM

Answer (score 2):

Aafreen's answer is correct and his advice is good.

Just to note a few things when sizing your oplog so that the RS102 does not re-occur.

The oplog size is going to depend on how much data you change and how often. It is very much application dependent (have a think about what your normal write patterns are). You basically want an oplog which is many times your largest time to recovery on failure or maintenance window.

**Oplog**

The oplog is a capped collection that stores all operations that modify the data stored in MongoDB. All members of the replica set have oplogs that allow them to maintain the current state of the database. Unless you modify the size of your oplog with the oplogSize option, the default size of the oplog will be as follows:

- For 64-bit Linux, Solaris, and FreeBSD systems, MongoDB will allocate
  5% of the available free disk space to the oplog.

  If this amount is smaller than a gigabyte, then MongoDB will allocate 1 gigabyte of space.
- For 64-bit OS X systems, MongoDB allocates 183 megabytes of space to
  the oplog.

  For 32-bit systems, MongoDB allocates about 48 megabytes of space to
  the oplog.

As I mentioned above, there's no formula per say, however, if you're performing a lot of writes (inserts/deletes/updates) then you may want a larger oplog (than 5%) whereas if it's mostly reads, you could possibly get away with less than 5%, it really depends on your app.

Here's another [introductory link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#replica-set-oplog-sizing) to sizing oplog, which may help explain things a little more and I also recommend reading the [Replication Fundamentals document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/).

The oplog on the primary is the most important and it is recommended that all oplogs (in the replica set) are the same size.

Comment: +1 for the extended advice on how to decide the size of oplog..By the way, "Aafreen's answer is correct and HIS advice is good."..I am a girl :P

Comment: So you are, I must humbly apologise.....I normally check when in doubt but this time I didn't. Sorry!

Comment: Oh just checked your profile..you work for 10gen! Wow cool :) I love MongoDB!